# web browser control not display PDF when its run as administrator

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am working on win form application in that i want display PDF in web browser control in i run application normally its working properly but if I run application as administrator PDF is not display in web browser control.

Comment: Can you show your code and describe the specific behavior when run as administrator?  At this point there is not enough information to begin to help you.